# Installing OpenBSD 7.0 on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, openbsd

I'm trying to install OpenBSD 7.0 on a Raspberry Pi 4, but I'm facing some issues. This is the tutorial I'm trying to follow: https://lzomedia.com/blog/installing-openbsd-7-on-raspberry-pi-3/ (The tutorial is for the Pi 3, but the instructions are the same for the 4 as well).

I'm able to boot from USB, however once it boots to the command prompt, hitting enter gives me the error "cannot open sd0a: /etc/random.seed: No such file or directory"

Any idea what could be the issue?

I've got miniroot.img on the SD card, and install.img on a USB drive.

Comment: Is it really "sd0a" in the error message or was it a typo when posting the question?

Comment: @ChanganAuto not a typo, it was "sd0a." Any idea why that is?

Comment: User error then. It should be "sda". Please review the tutorial.

Comment: @ChanganAuto May I know why it should be "sda?" This is typically a Linux convention, and I just wanted to know the significance of it stating "sd0a" instead. I've followed the instructions carefully, but I'm having trouble starting the installer itself.

Comment: The installer is a script (or more stitched together). It expects predictable target drive names.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I see, but I didn't name any of the drives. I just used "dd" to copy the respective img files to the drives. How can I fix this if this is indeed the issue?

Comment: Try redoing the instructions. At the point where is says "sda" make sure you're typing it correctly.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yup, I got no issues writing the images to the drive. The issue comes when I try to launch the installer. Here is when it fails and gives me the error message above. In the tutorial, that's the part that says "Installation Options." I can't get to that screen when booting the written image on the Pi. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

That is not an installer error, or at least not a serious one that will impede it from continuing.

That file is one of the sources of entropy for generating good random numbers with arc4andom() (see [this presentation](https://www.openbsd.org/papers/hackfest2014-arc4random/index.html) for details).  It is normally written upon system shutdown and read as it boots.  It doesn't exist on a new system (obviously), hence the message.

Most likely, the installer is still running, but your system's console isn't where you want it to be (e.g. it might be redirected to a serial port), so you don't see it on the screen. From the `INSTALL.arm64` file that accompanies the installation images and file sets (highlighted by me):

> Install on Raspberry Pi:
>
> As of OpenBSD 6.9, the standard miniroot supports at least the
> Raspberry Pi 3 and 4 with no additional firmware.  Some devices may
> not be functional with Pi 3+.  It is recommended that you install
> to a USB storage device.
>
> **The default system console is on the TTL serial interface on the
> TXD/RXD/GND pins of the https://pinout.xyz/ header on the board.
> It will be helpful to obtain an adapter (e.g. CP2102 USB-UART).
> If you have one, attach it to the pins and a computer; a command
> such as "cu -l cuaU0 -s 115200" (assuming cuaU0 is your serial
> port device) should connect you to the board's console.**
>
> If not, note that once the kernel has started running, by default you
> will only see output on the serial console.  To switch to displaying on
> the monitor instead, watch for the OpenBSD BOOTAA64 "boot>" prompt,
> and type "set tty fb0".
>
> Alternatively the system can be booted using UEFI firmware found at
> https://github.com/pftf/RPi4. Follow their instructions to install to an
> SD card and run the OpenBSD installer from USB. v1.21 is known to work;
> some newer versions may have problems.

Make sure to check OpenBSD's [FAQ](http://www.openbsd.org/faq), the `INSTALL` and `README` files, and the [man pages](http://man.openbsd.org) if you are looking for something more specific.  OpenBSD's documentation in famously good and thorough.